# Mysql queries for through tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Basically I have two tables,

1. Groups: with fields like location, city, country
2. Property Type :  with fields like 1BHK, 2BHK, 3BHK
3. Group_property_type : which is basically a through table with foreign key group_id and property_type_id

Now I want to add a exhaustive search function. which will take both the fields of groups table and property_type table. Any help with the SQL query?

I am using mysql

Comment: I am not good with sql stuff :( . I thought a few inputs from here will get me started :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Group_property_type GPT
JOIN    Groups G
    ON  GPT.group_id = G.group_id
JOIN    PropertyType PT
    ON  GPT.property_type_id = PT.property_type_id
WHERE   G.location LIKE '%' + @searchstring + '%'
    OR  G.city LIKE '%' + @searchstring + '%'
    OR  ...
```

Comment: yeah enough to get started, thanks man :)
Thing is I am not very familiar with the syntactic part. thanks :)

Comment: but if your database has correct records for all the foreign keys then this should work. What are the relations between tables?

Comment: group table and property type table are seperate and a group_property_type table as a through table

which has group_id a foreign key to groups table and property_id as a foreign key to property_type table

Comment: `property_id` or `property_type_id`? You have written the latter as the foreign key in your question.

Comment: my mistake it is actually property_type_id. There is no concern about the typos. you sure about left join?

Comment: Yes. If the `Group_property_type` table is the _through table_ then irrespective of the relation between tables this should work, because it is simple search you are performing.